# how to filter my data on the same page according to the origin click

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, filter, single-page-application

In my DB i've got a list of names with specifics origins.
In my navbar, i've got a link for each origin.
I'm new in angular and my first approach was to create a "page" for each origin.
My question is : is there any shortcut for doing that?
like : on click on the link A, i'm going on the page and i've got list of origin A. on click on the link B, i'm still going on the same page but i've got a list of origin B ...

controller laravel for each origin (origin 1,2,3 ...)

```
 public function index()
{
    $identity = name::orderBy('name')->where('origin_link', 1)->get();
    return response()->json($identity);
}
```

html angular (it's exactly same page for each origin)

```
<div class="ci">
<div class="container">
<ul *ngFor="let name of names">
    <li><a role="button">{{name.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

html for link

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="names">origin 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="names1">origin 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="names2">origin 3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="names3">origin 4</a>
 </div>
```

ts (for now, he gets all the list)

```
export class NamesComponent implements OnInit {
public names: string;

constructor(public namesService: NamesService
 ) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.namesService.index().subscribe((data:any) => {
  this.names= data;
 })
}
```

service

```
index(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/names');
}
```

Comment: Do you want for each origin page ?

Comment: yes @ArashHatami

Answer (score 0):

If you want page for each origin , I suggest you to use Route Parameters .
you should change that route :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'names/:id', component: NamesComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
]
```

and change routerlink:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/names',1]">origin 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/names',2]">origin 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/names',3]">origin 3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/names',4]">origin 4</a>
</div>
```

and in your NamesComponent you should check the parameters to load data:

```
id: string
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit(){
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
}
```

Comment: i got problem with this @ArashHatami, there is no reload when i click on link ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    if(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('id')){
      if (this.id === '1'){
 this.namesService.index().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.prenoms = data;
     })
      } else if (this.id === '2'){
 this.namesService.indexbis().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.prenoms = data;
     })
      }  else if (this.id === '3'){
 this.namesService.indexter().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.prenoms = data;
     })
  ... etc